# Ruby Gem: Axlslx RuntimeError: Can't add attachments after `mail` was called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, axlsx

I'm stepping thru all my `shop` records and sending them an email if an `order` is wrong. It works fine thru 2 or 
3 shops but after that I get this error:

`RuntimeError: Can't add attachments after`mail`was called.
Make sure to use attachments[]= before calling mail.`

This is my code for creating and sending the attachements:

```
 def order_report
    shops = Shop.where(subscribed: true, setup: true)
    shops.each do |shop|
      @sheet = OrderReport.new(shop)
      @sheet.create_order_workbook
      get_data_for_inside_email
      time = Time.now
      attachments["test_book.xlsx"] = File.read("test_book.xlsx")
      excel_sheet_line_count = %x{wc -l "test_book.xlsx"}.split[0].to_i #this is just seeing how many lines the file is.. an empty sheet returns as 13
      if excel_sheet_line_count > 13
        mail(to: "some_email@gmail.com", subject: "FBA Shipping Report for #{time.strftime("%B %d")}")
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding this here if anyone ever comes across this. I could never get the above code to work, but I found this and it works like a charm:

```
mail(to: "todd@gmail.com", 
        subject: "FBA Shipping Report for #{time.strftime("%B %d")}").attachments["problem_orders_#{shop.id}.xlsx"] = File.read("problem_orders_#{shop.id}.xlsx")
```